# ASP.net request validation & Razor — do I really need it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, razor, xss

I wonder if I really need ASP.net request validation (the one that throws "`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`")?

I use the Razor template engine and only output something from my database using:

- `DisplayFor`/`EditorFor` (escapes HTML)
- `@Model.SomeField` (escapes HTML)
- Specific fields that requires HTML markup specifically converted to `HtmlString` instances with HTML white-list sanitizing.

It seems like I don't need **any** request validation, and can disable it at all without having exceptions when user inputs HTML, can't I? Or I missing something?

what's preferred method of turning it off then?

Comment: If you sanitize and/or escape user input using other strategies, there is no need for request validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to disable RequestValidation. It is actually kind of a silly way to improve security, but it's Microsoft's attempt to make their stuff idiot-proof (in my opinion). "Idiot-proof" is a little harsh - doing security right is hard, and I'm not saying it is a bad thing, but if that is your only line of defense against XSS, then you may be in trouble.

That being said, it sounds like you need to have special characters in your requests - so you should disable it and be sure to escape/encode your output properly.

Here's a good resource for disabling it: [Request Validation in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx)

The relevant bits:

#### web.config (globally disable)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

#### method (for just the method where you send html)

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(string comment)
```

#### property (for just the one property that holds html)

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Prop1 { get;  set; }
```

In my opinion, you should keep it enabled globally, but disable it for as small of a part as you can. It's better to err on the safer side, and having additional layers of security is usually a good thing unless it over-complicates the system.

So, in summary, you do not need to have request validation if you are knowingly going to allow these kind of requests, but be careful with the data and make sure you don't open yourself up for XSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it on specific propertyes by adding the [AllowHtml] atribute.

But if you are not allowing HTML in purpose , then you should validate it , since someone could not only add markup but they could also add scripts like alert('tard')

then every time someone loads your page, will get insulted :(

Comment: That's my point: why I need validation, if I escape everything on output?